# Postgresql, Restrict update on specific columns (Read Only)

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to have postresql restrict/prevent an update on a specific record if the update includes changes to specific columns?

How would this be implemented. A trigger/constraint? What would be the most efficient way to implement this?

I am using version 9.1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The easiest way is to create `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that will compare `OLD` and `NEW` row and  `RAISE EXCEPTION` if the change to the row is forbidden.

Comment: [Example for such a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56083320), from another SO question.

Answer (score 7):

No, but it should be pretty trivial to write. 
Just set up a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that compares old field against new field and does a `RAISE ERROR` if they're different.
The pgSQL docs have a few examples of how to write a trigger function.

Answer (score 2):

Several solutions are available:

- You can use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, as already proposed in other answers. Another Stack Overflow answer shows an [example for such a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56083320).
- You can split your table into two tables, with a 1:1 relationship between them. Then, you can provide `SELECT` and `UPDATE` access to one table and only `SELECT` access to the other.
- You can provide `UPDATE` access to only a subset of columns of the table: `GRANT UPDATE(col1, col2)` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3281750)).
- You can provide read-only access to the table and create a `VIEW` with the updateable columns of the table, and grant `UPDATE` access to that.
- You can hide the table behind a `FUNCTION` using `SECURITY DEFINER`. The table itself would not provide UPDATE access, instead users can only update the table through the function.

Inspired by [this list](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/656#discussioncomment-335362). See also [a more detailed look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75504865) at these solutions in another answer of mine, in the context of the Supabase system.