# PostgreSQL trigger to avoid update in a column

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a PostgreSQL database with a table called `product`. In this table I have an autoincrement column named `auxId` (not the table's primary key). I want to avoid any update on this column. How can this be done using a PostgreSQL trigger?

I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stop_change_on_auxId()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 IF NEW.auxId <> OLD.auxId THEN

 END IF;
 
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$

-- trigger to avoid updates on auxId
CREATE TRIGGER avoid_auxid_changes
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON product
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE stop_change_on_auxId();
```

but I believe this will stop the update for the whole row. I just need to avoid the update on the `auxId` field but allow any other update on its row.

Comment: Why not just use column level privileges for this? Like; `GRANT UPDATE(col1,col2 /* no "auxId" here*/) ON tbl TO role`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you basically want to make the `auxid` column immutable to the outside world, here you go:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stop_change_on_auxId()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  -- always reset the auxId to the value already stored
  NEW.auxId := OLD.auxId;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$


CREATE TRIGGER avoid_auxid_changes
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON product
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE stop_change_on_auxId();
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution as you can not respond in any way, could lead to a lot of debugging. If you're fine with "silent" procedures, this is okayish.

Comment: Same, as above, the trigger should also alert the attempt.

Answer (score 20):

Sure, just throw an error when the column is changed:

```
CREATE FUNCTION noupdate() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF NEW.auxid <> OLD.auxid THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'not allowed';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER noupdate
   BEFORE UPDATE ON product FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE noupdate();
```

This solution allows updates on all other columns, as long as `auxid` is not modified.

Comment: will this stop the update for other fields? I need the updating to be ignored just for the auxId field. The others, can be updated.

Comment: Other columns are not affected. Don't ask, try it out.

Comment: Attempt at clarification: Other columns are affected in the sense that an UPDATE statement cannot modify any column if it tries to modify `auxid`. I think OP wants the other field updates to succeed in such a case.

Comment: @tanius Yes, I understood. My solution allows updates on all other columns, as long as `auxid` is not modified.

Comment: Note that `NULL` can't be compared to value and will return `NULL` instead of `TRUE` in this case!