# Not allow postgres user to override default column value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tabley(
   log          text, -- something like this you get the point
   created      timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

And I want to let a postgres user `INSERT` their own arbitrary `log` but I want to make sure they are not allowed to set their own arbitrary `created`. Is there any clean way to enforce this?

Comment: I think following will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411735/postgresql-restrict-update-on-specific-columns-read-only

Comment: @Maxqueue that's an interesting idea, using an on-insert trigger to set the `created` field so that it can't be overridden